# SecureSocial Unresolved dependency play 2.4.2 securesocial 2.1.4

Tags: playframework, securesocial

I'm having a devil of a time getting this dependency to resolve with play 2.4.2

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this build.sbt file.

```html
name := """ltweb"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

resolvers ++= Seq(
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
   "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4"
)

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"



// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Comment: SecureSocial is not compatiple with Play 2.4. You should try an alternative library.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

Latest milestone - 3.0-M4 as of this writing - is compatible with Play 2.4.